# Oracle, DataStax academy : Kernel Panic - not syncing

Tags: installation, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm suffering from kernel panic issue. Below is capture of the error. Please help me :

[image: error message]

Comment: There is not enough info on here as to when & where (e.g. install/upgrade/etc.,) exactly this is happening or what is the system configurations (e.g. C* version/OS/etc.,) under test, reproducible steps, etc., Please refer to [this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question with enough details for the other members to help triage the problem and provide a [path to] solution.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the problem is i don't allocate processor for it. Just go to system of the VM and allocate more processor to it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).